# My Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword function does not register users

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

My Firebase `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function does not register users. The app has a register method but it doesnt work, instead it requires me to register a user manually in Firebase Authentication page, then it signs in from there.

I get the following error messages when after trying to sign in

```
W/System  (11597): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

I/flutter (11597): [firebase_auth/user-not-found] There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.
```

below is the Auth Class that contains Register and the Sign in functions.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

abstract class BaseAuth {
  Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged;

  Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    String email,
    String password,
  );
  Future<String> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    String email,
    String password,
  );

  Future<String> CurrentUser();
  Future<void> signOut();
  Future<String> signInWithGoogle();
}

class Auth implements BaseAuth {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  @override
  Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged =>
      _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map((User user) => user?.uid);

  @override
  Future<String> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
      (await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password))
        .user
        .uid;
  }

  @override
  Future<String> CurrentUser() async {
    return (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser).uid;
  }

  @override
  Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    return (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password))
        .user
        .uid;
  }

  @override
  Future<String> signInWithGoogle() {
    Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
      final GoogleSignInAccount account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication _auth = await account.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: _auth.accessToken, idToken: _auth.idToken);
      return (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user.uid;
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() {
    return FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want the user to register and return the user id, right?
I have written this code, check it out, please

```
Future<String> signUp2(String email, String password) async {
    AuthResult res;
    String userID;
    try {
      res = await _instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      userID = res.user.uid;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
    print(userID);
    return userID;
  }
```

`Authentication.signUp2('Example@example.com', '111111');`

Comment: what do I return on my return statement and changing the future type to 'void' throws an error

Comment: It actually works, Thank you. But the ```AuthResult``` function has now been changed to ```UserCredential```

Comment: No problem, Yeah I think I'm using old versions of firebase auth package.

Comment: Could you please approve the answer

Comment: Consider it Done